# How move a button to the right side of the container in Material design

Tags: angular, material-design

I'm trying to get a button to move to the right side of the container, I used several forms but I can not get it, somehow the `style="float: right;"`

Maybe this is not a thing, Material design, I have no experience in front-end developments.

---

[image]

```
 <md-toolbar color="primary">
    <span><md-icon>mood</md-icon></span>

    <span>Material in Angular 2!</span>

    <button md-icon-button style="float: left;" [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <md-icon style="float: left;">more_vert</md-icon>
    </button>
  </md-toolbar>
```

---

[image]

```
<button md-icon-button style="float: right;" [md-menu-trigger-for]="menu">
      <md-icon style="float: right;">more_vert</md-icon>
```

I'd like to move it here. I'm sorry for my bad English. I hope you can understand me.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing the class on the text `<span>` which allows it to fill the space:

[See full example here.](https://material.angular.io/components/component/toolbar)

```css
.example-fill-remaining-space {
  // This fills the remaining space, by using flexbox. 
  // Every toolbar row uses a flexbox row layout.
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<md-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Application Title</span>

  <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
  <span class="example-fill-remaining-space"></span>

  <span>Right Aligned Text</span>
</md-toolbar>
```

Comment: Thanks for your time I feel so stupid now, and there was the solution in the documentation.

Comment: How can I move a button to the right side of the container in Material Design when the container is not md-toolbar?

Comment: You can still use flex. Look into `display: flex` for the container and `flex: 1 1 auto` for a child to fill in the space like the example above

Comment: So.... this works, but isn't injecting dummy elements into HTML purely for purposes of styling kind of a regression toward 1990's practices? (Remember when people used to repeat `&nbsp;` to achieve padding?) And if we are regressing toward 90's practices, why not just go back to using `table` for layout? (it also works) `<table style="width:100%"><tr><td style="text-align:left">Left</td><td style="text-align:right">Right</td></tr></table>`

Comment: @nothingisnecessary I think you're being a little facetious. No one is recommending going back to the table layouts - as far as semantic mark up goes, `<span>` is perfectly sensible for an inline element to cover some area.

Comment: I ended up using table. Sue me.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary you do you.